# Converting String to UTF-16 Representation in Java

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I'm trying to convert Java Strings into their various encoding types and print it out.

For example, `luke` would be `6C 75 6B 65` in `UTF-8` and `UTF-16` while the Chinese character `猪` would would be `E7 8C AA` in `UTF-8` and `732A` in `UTF-16`.

How do I write a function that does that?

```
new String( org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHex(str.getBytes("UTF-16")));
```

doesn't seem to work for `UTF-16`.

Comment: The UTF-16 encoding of `luke` would be `00 6C 00 75 00 6B 00 65`. `6C 75 6B 65` would be `汵步`.

Comment: @duskwuff I'm using [this tool](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) since I don't know how to do it in Java yet.  How did you do the conversion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```java
public class UseTheForce {
    public static void main(final String[] args)
        throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException {
        for (final byte b : args[0].getBytes(args[1])) {
            System.out.printf("%1$02X ", (b & 0xFF));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Test

```
$ java UseTheForce luke US-ASCII
6C 75 6B 65

$ java UseTheForce luke UTF-8
6C 75 6B 65

$ java UseTheForce luke UTF-16
FE FF 00 6C 00 75 00 6B 00 65

$ java UseTheForce luke UTF-16BE
00 6C 00 75 00 6B 00 65

$ java UseTheForce luke UTF-16LE
6C 00 75 00 6B 00 65 00

$ java UseTheForce luke UTF-32
00 00 00 6C 00 00 00 75 00 00 00 6B 00 00 00 65
```

May the force be with you.

**UPDATE**

As describe in [Formatter.html#detail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#detail), the `(b & 0xFF)` part is not necessary.

Comment: thanks buddy!  Mine did actually work.  I just forgot the FE FF that's in front for strictly UTF-16.

Comment: Can I know why (b & 0xFF) ?

Comment: @Mubasher That's making the signed 8-bit value into an unsigned which, I just realized, is not necessary.